# Result of a writing prompt?

Tags: single-word-requests

Say you have a writing prompt, meant to inspire people and get them to write, by providing them with an interesting or thought-provoking premise. Say you have five people, who wrote five different stories based on the same prompt. What would you call those stories, besides just "stories" or "writing"? Is there a specific word you could use to refer to the product of such writing prompts? I'd like to be able to use that specific word in sentences like this:

*"So close, yet so far" is a short story written by Steve. The short story is a [word] of Bill's writing prompt.*

Comment: Why have you capitalized *Writing Prompt*?

Comment: @JasonBassford I thought I'd be nice and just accept a random and pointless edit to my question. Wasn't really my idea to capitalize it, but I rolled it back now.

Comment: If you are writing an article about that, you may want to sound more literary....

Comment: @Lambie What do you mean?

Comment: Have you read my answer? result and product are not very much fun.

Comment: @Lambie Don't worry then, I don't need it for an article or any other writing. I just needed a word to be able to refer to these specific pieces of writing for something I'm working on (non-writing related).

Comment: I'll pass, then.

Answer (score 1):

The short story is a [**product**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/product) of Bill's writing prompt.

> **2 a** (1) : something produced; *especially* : COMMODITY 1 (2) : something (such as a service) that is marketed or sold as a commodity
>   **b** : something resulting from or necessarily following from a set of conditions · a *product* of his environment
>
> This book is the *product* of many years of hard work.

Alternatively, the short story is a [**result**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/result) of Bill's writing prompt.

> **1 a** : to proceed or arise as a consequence, effect, or conclusion · death *resulted* from the disease
>
> **b** : to have an issue or result · the disease *resulted* in death

Answer (score 1):

It's a [**response**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/response) to the prompt. Here are some examples of this exact expression in use:

> 6 months ago I wrote a response to a prompt, now it's a full length novel on Amazon! But I can't remember writing it.
>   <sub>[Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/WritingPrompts/comments/8ft54b/wp_6_months_ago_i_wrote_a_response_to_a_prompt/)</sub>

> [Lesson 22: Write an essay in response to a prompt](https://learnzillion.com/lesson_plans/12062-lesson-22-write-an-essay-in-response-to-a-prompt/)

> The things you write in response to a prompt may also end up as worthwhile material in their own right.
>   <sub>[Writing Prompts 101](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/writing-prompts-101/)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The short story was inspired by Bill's writing prompt.

**One hopes that people are inspired to write stories.**

But there are surely many others ways to say this as well.

- grew out of
- sprang from

short and sweet